# Find the gradient $\nabla(g\circ f)$ in all points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=(xy,x^2+y^2)$, $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g(t,s)=\exp(2t+s)$. Find the gradient $\nabla(g\circ f)$ in all points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ once by taking the partial derivative of $g\circ f$ and once by making use of the gradient chain rule: $\nabla(g\circ f)(x_0)=\nabla g(f(x_0))\nabla f(x_0)$.

---

First taking the partial derivative. Let $h:=(g\circ f)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\nabla h(x,y)&=\nabla \exp(2xy+x^2+y^2)=(\frac{dh}{dx},\frac{dh}{dy})\\
&=(2(x+y)e^{x^2+2xy+y^2},2(x+y)e^{x^2+2xy+y^2}).
\end{align*}

---

But the chain rule is confusing me. It should be $\nabla(g(f(x,y)) \nabla f(x,y)=\nabla g(xy,x^2+y^2)\nabla f(x,y)$, right? But isn't $\nabla g(xy,x^2+y^2)$ not the same as what I just did above, i.e. $\nabla g(xy,x^2+y^2)=\nabla \exp(2xy+x^2+y^2)$?

- Where is my mistake?
- How would I take the gradient of e.g. $f(x,y)$ in the first place? Do I not get a three dimensional vector?

Comment: $f$ doesn't even have a gradient since it's vector valued. It does have a Jacobian though, which is what you need to make the chain rule work.

Comment: @ChristianSykes well in my experience, if one looks at say a book on fluid dynamics, no one stops to wonder what the gradient of a 3D velocity is (its of course just defined as the Jacobian)

Answer (score 2):

No, calculating $\nabla g(xy,x^2+y^2)$ gives not what you've calculated before. The main point is that chain rule can be confusing, when you interpret the formula wrong. With the chain rule you now apply the nabla operator to the variables $t,s$ for $g$.
$\nabla g(xy,x^2+y^2)$ means that you calculate $\nabla g(t,s)$ and insert $xy$ for $t$ as well as $x^2+y^2$ for $s$. And for $f$: Since $f$ is a vectorial function, you get here a Jacobian matrix. So the chain rule tells you in your case
$$ \nabla (g \circ f)(x,y)^T=\nabla g(xy,x^2+y^2)^T Df(x,y)$$
which is nothing else then a vector matrix multiplication (vector from the left).
In general the chain rule tells you
$$D(g \circ f)(x,y)=Dg(f(x,y)) Df(x,y)$$
where these can be Jacobian matrices of different sizes. Most important is to understand $Dg(f(x,y))$, which is the Jacobian matrix of $g$, but evaluated in $f(x,y)$. Note that I use Jacobians for the chain rule here, which is more general. The Jacobian of scalar functions gives the gradient as a row vector.

Comment: I see, thank you. So $\nabla g(t,s)=(2e^{s+2t},e^{s+2t})$ means that $\nabla g(f(x,y))=(2e^{x^2+y^2+2xy},e^{x^2+y^2+2xy})$, correct? My part on partial differentiation was correct though, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. And yes, your partial differentations look good. Now try to calculate the Jacobian of f and do the vector-matrix multiplication

Comment: One small subtlety that MrMatzetoni alluded to in his answer, but would be easy to miss is that the chain rule formula above works only if you work with the row vector corresponding to the gradient. If you treat all gradients as row vectors when using the chain rule, you won't run into any problems.

Comment: Good point! I edited my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between $\nabla f(g) = (\nabla f)(g) = \nabla f \circ g $ and $\nabla(f(g)) = \nabla (f\circ g)$. This is more confusing when the slight abuse of notation $f=f(x)$ is used.

The gradient $\nabla f(v)$, if interpreted as the matrix in the 'usual standard basis' of the derivative of $f$ at $v$, is also known for functions $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ as the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $v$.